# Почему не изменяться ssl сертификат при изменение в nginx?

Tags: nginx, debian, ssl

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать чтоб понять причину проблемы?

Взяли сервер у **Google** на **debian**

На нем расположили 2 сайта

Установили на один сайт сертификат без проблем

Со вторым сайтом возникла проблема, на нем не устанавливается(не изменяется) сертификат

То есть сертификат **instance-1.europe-west4-a.c.my-project-site-name.internal** не как не меняется

Что делали?

Получил сертификат, прописал его в конфиге nginx, провели тест nginx -t(все ok), перезапустил nginx, очистили кеш в браузере но сертификат не изменился

Всегда показывается один и тот же сертификат(Самописный по всей видимости) **instance-1.europe-west4-a.c.my-project-site-name.internal**

Comment: Проверили, что сертификат не прописан в каком-нибудь другом месте конфига?

Comment: Этот сертификат не когда в жизни не устанавливался и не задавался

Comment: Вами - может, и не задавался, кем-то другим - видимо, всё-таки задавался. Тщательно проверьте, что сертификат не прописан в каком-нибудь другом месте конфига

Comment: Вы были правы сертификат переопределялся в разкомментированной строкой в "include snippets/snakeoil.conf;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в одной строке "include snippets/snakeoil.conf;" которая была разкомментирована в конфигурационам файле сайта nginx